# Problems including inline JS in wordpress 4.2.2, wp_add_inline_script not working

Tags: wordpress

i want to put inline js in worpress and according to the wordpress docs the wp_add_line_script is for this, BUT it doesn't exists in the functions.wp-scripts.php file . The other way i tried was using WP_Scripts::add_inline_script but this method doesn't exits as well.

It is funny that wp_add_inline_style works so i can doit with CSS but no with JS..

So i need to include inline JS but cannot use the docs function and i don't want to do 
`echo "<script> 
//code 
</script>`

So what can i do?, and why this functions are not in wordpress 4.2.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i end up implementing a static method in a helper class that prints the JS before body get closed, i think this can be impruved but for me worked...

With this class i can include an array of js/css files and inline javascript like:

```
    Assets::registerCSS(['jquery-ui.min.css', 'jquery.tagsinput-revisited.css']);
    Assets::registerJS(['jquery-ui.min.js', 'jquery.tagsinput-revisited.js'], ['jquery']);
```

and the inline JS like:

```
Assets::registerInlineJS($script);
```

Where $script is the JS code without the tags `<script> </script>`

This class is a piece of a plugin i'm working and it should work too for other plugins..in my case in the root folder of my plugin i have two folders named css and js thats why i call plugin_dir_url(**DIR**) . "js/$file" to look for the .js files
Hope this helps somebody

```
class Assets {

public static function registerJS(Array $files = [], Array $deps = []) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        wp_enqueue_script(basename($file, '.js'), plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . "js/$file", $deps, false, false);
    }
}

public static function registerCSS(Array $files = [], Array $deps = []) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        wp_enqueue_style(basename($file, '.css'), plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . "css/$file", $deps, false);
    }
}

public static function registerInlineJS($js) {
    add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', function() use ($js) {
        echo '<script>';
        echo $js;
        echo '</script>';
    });
}
```

}